# Sane-Cli sane up EPERM Error: Server not Starting

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js

I am using sane-cli in an ember app and when I try to use sane up inside the sails folder. I am getting this error. Can anyone help me to fix it?

I have already tried `sudo npm install` inside the server folder and globally.

Error log ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfR2R.png)):

```
client   | Could not start watchman
client   | was unable to use: "events", fell back to: "polling"
server   | debug: initializing sails-hook-dev...
server   | events.js:160
server   |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
server   |       ^
server   |
server   | Error: watch /home/ayush/Code/sails/server/api/blueprints EPERM
server   |     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
server   |     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1443:19)
server   |     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1470:11)
server   |     at createFsWatchInstance
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:37:15)
server   |     at setFsWatchListener
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:80:15)
server   |     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:228:14)
server   |     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:407:19)
server   |     at FSWatcher.<anonymous>
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:455:19)
server   |     at FSWatcher.<anonymous>
(/home/ayush/Code/sails/server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-
handler.js:460:16)
server   |     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
client   | Proxying to http://127.0.0.1:1337
client   | Livereload server on http ://localhost:49153
client   | Serving on http ://localhost:4200/
```

Comment: If you put the stacktrace as text (code format) in question, it is easier to people to copy and search, with image it is difficult.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question. Does this help? @Sangharsh